# Is it possible to find out an app installation date on iOS?

Tags: ios

Is there a way to find out the date of installation of an application that was added to my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

On iTunes on a computer. You can see your app & subscription purchase history.

Open itunes.
At the top select the iTunes Store.
On the right hand side click on "purchased".

Comment: Purchase and installation are different things, though. But it may be a good approximation anyhow.

Comment: Yes, they're different but if you know of a better way, please share.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know a better way. I just thought it important to point out the difference, if only to prod other contributors to look for better ways. It is quite possible that the OP really is more interested in the purchase date than the installation date, anyhow.